# Why does the same computer appear multiple times on the network?

Tags: network

As can be seen below, the same computer shows up several times when I go to browse network. It only happens with this single laptop.

[image: multiple computers on network]

What causes this?

Comment: Do you connect it with both cable and wifi (at different times)?  Do you have any other Apple devices on the network?

Comment: the laptop showing multiple times is only ever connected by wifi. there's also another macbook and a mac mini, and a mac pro on the same network, nonen of which have this issue.

Comment: This looks like a possible Bonjour related issue. Download the freeware [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/). Using Bonjour Browser, find out if there is multiple entries of your computer listed under the "Apple File Sharing" section. Also, does this laptop appear more than once in other Bonjour related features such as "iTunes Music Sharing"?